# Most succinct implementation of a floating point constraint function with wrap-around overflow

Tags: function, numbers, floating-point, overflow

I'm looking for the most succinct and general implementation of the following function:

```
float Constrain(float value, float min, float max);
```

Where Constrain() bounds `value` in the range `[min, float)`.  Ie, the range includes min but excludes `max` and `values` greater than `max` or less than `min` wrap around in a circle.  Ie, in a similar way to integers over/underflow.

The function should pass the following tests:

```
Constrain(  0.0,  0.0,  10.0) ==  0.0
Constrain( 10.0,  0.0,  10.0) ==  0.0
Constrain(  5.0,  0.0,  10.0) ==  5.0
Constrain( 15.0,  0.0,  10.0) ==  5.0
Constrain( -1.0,  0.0,  10.0) ==  9.0
Constrain(-15.0,  0.0,  10.0) ==  5.0

Constrain(  0.0, -5.0,   5.0) ==  0.0
Constrain(  5.0, -5.0,   5.0) == -5.0
Constrain(  0.0, -5.0,   5.0) ==  0.0
Constrain( 10.0, -5.0,   5.0) ==  0.0    
Constrain( -6.0, -5.0,   5.0) ==  4.0
Constrain(-10.0, -5.0,   5.0) ==  0.0
Constrain( 24.0, -5.0,   5.0) ==  4.0

Constrain(  0.0, -5.0,   0.0) == -5.0
Constrain(  5.0, -5.0,   0.0) == -5.0
Constrain( 10.0, -5.0,   0.0) == -5.0
Constrain( -3.0, -5.0,   0.0) == -3.0     
Constrain( -6.0, -5.0,   0.0) == -1.0
Constrain(-10.0, -5.0,   0.0) == -5.0
```

Note that the `min` param can be assumed to be always numerically less than `max`.

There is probably a very simple formula to solve this question but and I'm being spectacularly dumb not knowing the generalised solution to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *almost* looking for the `fmod` function. `fmod(x,y)` returns the remainder on dividing `x` by `y`, both being `double`s. The sign of the result is the same as that of `x` (equivalently, the corresponding integer-part function is the one that rounds towards zero), and that's why it's only *almost* what you want. So, if `x>=lo` then `lo+fmod(x-lo,hi-lo)` is the Right Thing, but if `x<lo` then `hi+fmod(x-lo,hi-lo)` is oh-so-nearly the Right Thing except that when `x<lo` and the result could be either `lo` or `hi` you get `hi` instead of `lo`.

So. You can split three ways:

```
double Constrain(x,lo,hi) {
  double t = fmod(x-lo,hi-lo);
  return t<0 ? t+hi : t+lo;
}
```

or you can use `floor` instead [EDITED because the first version of this wasn't what I meant at all]:

```
double Constrain(x,lo,hi) {
  double t = (x-lo) / (hi-lo);
  return lo + (hi-lo) * (t-floor(t));
}
```

Take your pick if what you care about is comprehensibility; try them both if what you care about is performance.

Comment: Almost fmod (and fmodf) indeed. But not quite.  Which was what was doing my head in.  I think I like the bottom one best.  Less branches (depending on how floor() is implemented in libc of course).  I will give them a try and report my results.

Comment: Bummer.  Second implementation option doesn't pass the tests.  First does.

Comment: (Er, in case it isn't clear: I fixed the broken code; what's there now should pass the tests.)

Answer (score 1):

lrint() may be faster.

```
inline double fwrap(double x, double y)
{
  return x - y * lrint(x / y - 0.5);
}

double constrain(double x, double lo, double hi)
{
  return fwrap(x, hi - lo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

lrint() may be faster.

```
inline double fwrap(double x, double y)
{
  return x - y * lrint(x / y - 0.5);
}

double constrain(double x, double lo, double hi)
{
  return fwrap(x - lo, hi - lo) + lo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
double constrain(double value, double min, double max)
{
    double Range = max - min;

    if (value < min)
        value = max - (max - value ) % (Range + 1); // Range+1 for inclusive

    if (value > max)
        value = (value - min) % (Range) + min; // Range(+0) for exclusive

    return value;
}
```