# Constraint behavior for a range of floating point numbers?

Tags: c#, math, range

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304423/most-succinct-implementation-of-a-floating-point-constraint-function-with-wrap-a) question for ideas on implementing a constraint/wrap for a given range.

From that I could ascertain the following

**[n1, n2)**

```
float Wrap(float x, float lo, float hi)
{
    return x % Math.Abs(lo - hi);
}
```

Which only works with positive numbers so this was advised

```
float Constrain(float x, float lo, float hi)
{
    float t = (x - lo) % (hi - lo);

    return t < 0 ? t + hi : t + lo;
}
```

I'm still uncertain how I can get the following range constraints from the above code and would like some help?

**[n1, n2]**

**(n1, n2]**

Comment: In the `(n1, n2)` case, what would you wrap `n1` or `n2` to?

Comment: I would presume a small epsilon value either side of the upper/lower limit.  I shall remove that as it isn't necessary.

Comment: Similarly, given e.g. `[0, 1]`, would you map 2 to 0 or 1, or to 1 minus a small epsilon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(n1, n2]**

```
float constrainExclusiveInclusive(float x, float lo, float hi){
    float result = Constrain(x, lo, hi);
    if (result == lo){result = hi;}
    return result;
}
```

**[n1, n2]**

```
float constrainInclusiveInclusive(float x, float lo, float hi){
    float result = Constrain(x, lo, hi);
    if (result == lo){
        //somehow decide whether you want x to wrap to lo or hi
        if (moonIsInTheSeventhHouse()){
            result = lo;
        }
        else{
            result = hi;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**(n1, n2)**

```
float constrainExclusiveExclusive(float x, float lo, float hi){
    float result = Constrain(x, lo, hi);
    if (result == lo){
        throw new ArgumentException("No answer exists for the given inputs");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice handling of the edge cases. Odd that `[n1, n2]` could wrap `n1` to `n2` or vice-versa, but what else can you do?

Comment: One way of deciding is to wrap to `lo` if `(x <= lo)`, and wrap to `hi` if `(x >= hi)`. That will prevent the unintuitive case where `constrainInclusiveInclusive(x,y,x)` returns `y`.